# Pycharm - view full commit message

Tags: pycharm

Is there any way to show the full commit message in PyCharm? I've been through the settings, and I can't see the option. In SourceTree, the log/description shows the first line of the message, but the full message can be seen in the pane below.

If it cannot be shown in the Version Control > Log panel, how can I access the full commit message in PyCharm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the full commit message on PyCharm,

Open vcs log panel by Version Control > Log. Now bring the mouse pointer to the end of the panel so that the pointer becomes the `drag-able` shape (see the pointer on the image below [Kubuntu]). now drag the commit detail pane to top, so that you can see the full commit message on the blue underlined area.

[image: pycharm vcs log panel]